# Prove or disprove: $\phi(Ax,y)=\phi(x,A^Ty)$

Tags: bilinear-form

Let $\phi$ a bilinear form. Then $\phi(Ax,y)=\phi(x,A^Ty)$ for each $A \in M_n(\mathbb{K})$

I assumed that this statement is true (I couldn't find counterexamples). So I tried proving this by the properties of bilinear forms:

$\phi(u+v,w)= \phi(u,w) + \phi(v,w)$ and $\phi(\lambda u, v) = \lambda \phi(u,v)$

$\phi(u,v+w)= \phi(u,v) + \phi(u,w)$ and $\phi(u, \lambda v) = \lambda \phi(u,v)$

I tried to transform this equations to prove my task. I'm stuck here.

Can you give me a hint?

Comment: Of course, you have an extra comma on the right-hand side of your equality, both in the title and in the first line. :)

Comment: Haha thanks for the hint^^^I corrected it

Answer (score 1):

Let $\varphi:\mathbb{K}^n\times\mathbb{K}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{K}$ a bilinear form and let $M:=(\varphi(e_i,e_j))_{1\leqslant i,j\leqslant n}$ where $(e_i)_{1\leqslant i\leqslant n}$ is a base of $\mathbb{K}^n$. Thus for $(X,Y)\in\mathbb{K}^n\times\mathbb{K}^n$, if $X=\sum_{i=1}^{n^2}X_i e_i$ and $Y=\sum_{i=1}^{n^2}Y_ie_i$ we have
$$ \varphi(X,Y)=\sum_{1\leqslant i,j\leqslant n^2}X_iY_j\varphi(e_i,e_j)=X^TMY $$
It follows that for all $(X,Y)\in\mathbb{K}^n\times\mathbb{K}^n$ and $A\in\mathcal{M}_n(\mathbb{K})$ we have
$$ \varphi(AX,Y)=(AX)^TMY=X^TA^TMY $$
and
$$ \varphi(X,A^TY)=X^TMA^TY $$
thus $\varphi(AX,Y)=\varphi(X,A^TY)$ only if $A^TM=MA^T$.

Comment: Just to make sure, that I understood this correctly: 

If I represent my bilinear form $\phi$ as a matrix $M$. Then $\phi(AX,Y)=(AX)^tMY=X^tA^tMY$. If I do the same for $\phi(X,A^tY)$ it is $= X^tMA^tY$. So the statement is true only if: $A^tM=MA^t$. I'm a litte bit confused since you write the $t$ for transposed before the matrix. 

So the statement is in general false and true if a certain condition is given.

Comment: I edited my answer, now you using your notation for the transposition. Indeed the statement is false in general, but if you add the condition $A^TM=MA^T$ then it is true.

Comment: Thanks for your help. It is clear for me now.